# Align a label to text of first RadioButton

Tags: android, alignment, baseline

I have a `TableLayout` with 2 columns: label and input field (`Spinner`, `EditText`, `RadioGroup`). I want to align the label for the `RadioGroup` to be exactly in vertical alignment with the text of the first radio button. The Text "Take it" shall be on the red line. How to do that? Is it possible?

[image: example with label -> gravity=top]

Here is the XML - stripped down to the relevant `TableRow`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/layoutEditMedication1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:padding="16dp"
  tools:context=".Main" >

  <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/buttons" >

    <TableLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:shrinkColumns="1"
      android:stretchColumns="1" >

      <TableRow style="@style/EditMedicationTableRowT" >

        <TextView
          style="@style/EditMedicationLabel"
          android:layout_gravity="top"
          android:text="@string/i_need_to_take" />

        <RadioGroup
          style="@style/EditMedicationTableRowB"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical" >

          <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioScheduleDaily"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/schedule_daily" />

          <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioScheduleSpecial"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/schedule_special" />
        </RadioGroup>
      </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
  </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the used styles are:

```
<resources>
    <style name="EditMedicationTableRowT">
        <item name="android:paddingTop">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    </style>

    <style name="EditMedicationTableRowB">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">8dp</item>
        </style>

    <style name="EditMedicationLabel">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I know that I could make two `TableRows` with two different `RadioGroups` each with one `RadioButton` and then programmatically code something that makes them look as if they where one `RadioGroup`. But maybe there is a simple solution.

API is 8 and up.

Comment: Could you post your layout's XML?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<TextView
  style="@style/EditMedicationLabel"
  android:layout_gravity="top"
  android:paddingBottom="0dp"
  android:text="@string/i_need_to_take" />
```

Comment: sorry, didn't see your answer. In the meantime I did the thing with the tree table rows and group them by code (last paragraph in OP) - thx anyway